# Can't start GlassFish 4 on Windows 10 - Netbeans 8.0

Tags: glassfish, netbeans-8.2

I have download and installed GlassFish.

However can't start it.

Having this error "Could not start GlassFish Server: HTTP or HTTPS listener port is occupied while server is not running"

I don't have Oracle or SQLServe installed, neither easyphp.

thx for ur help.

Comment: this helps me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004517/cannot-start-glassfish-4-1-from-within-netbeans-8-0-1-service-area http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521740/could-not-start-glassfish-4-0-windows-port-1527-address-already-in-use Thanks